# Seeder command not working Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I am new to laravel I am trying to follow a tutorial in which I create a Database Seeder for the DB. So for that, I have used `php artisan make:seeder ArticlesTableSeeder` command

**Seeder**

```
class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Let's truncate our existing records to start from scratch.
        Article::truncate();

        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

        // And now, let's create a few articles in our database:
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            Article::create([
                'title' => $faker->sentence,
                'body' => $faker->paragraph,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I run the `php artisan db:seed --class=ArticlesTableSeeder` command I have got this error

`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Article' not found`

I do have a article modal

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I have searched for this error and found the maximum of them are due to spelling mistakes. I think I don't have a spelling mistake here. What is wrong with this code ?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add a Use for your model in your seeder?

Comment: Did you posted the whole seeder file? If not, you need to import the model from the `App` namespace.

Comment: YEs i posted the whole seeder file.

Comment: Just add `use App\Article;` at the top in `ArticlesTableSeeder` class file

Answer (score 1):

```
use App\Article;

class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        public function run()
        {
            // Let's truncate our existing records to start from scratch.
            Article::truncate();

            $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

            // And now, let's create a few articles in our database:
            for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
                Article::create([
                    'title' => $faker->sentence,
                    'body' => $faker->paragraph,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to include your model inside your controller, so you are getting `class not found error`. Add this line to your controller before the class

```
use App\Article;
```

Comment: Can you explain why we use truncate()?

Comment: To truncate the entire table, which will remove all rows and reset the auto-incrementing ID to zero. you can get the definition here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#deletes

Comment: Simply in one line `it will reset your table`

Answer (score 1):

You missed to include your model inside your controller, so you are getting class not found error. Add this line to your controller before the class

use App\Models\Article;

Answer (score -1):

All you should do is add `\App\` before `Article` or simply add `use \App\Article`

```
class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Let's truncate our existing records to start from scratch.
        \App\Article::truncate();

        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

        // And now, let's create a few articles in our database:
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            \App\Article::create([
                'title' => $faker->sentence,
                'body' => $faker->paragraph,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Prakash we use truncate to remove all records in the table an then start over with new fresh table :)

Comment: @Prakash take a look in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#deletes) for more infos

Comment: @Prakash Is it workin for you ?? if yes can you accept and upvote my answer ^^